# Can legitimised bastards be heirs?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm the petty king of Munster.  I have a daughter by my ex-wife and my new wife isn't very fertile.  I gave a courtier a good tumble, she gave me a son, and I legitimised him.

I was expecting the legitimate bastard to then become the heir - however, my daughter is still the heir.  I'd really like to make my son the heir, to get rid of the "female heir" negative opinion from my vassals.  Why did this happen?

N.B. - My son is considered "my son", he is of my dynasty.

Comment: They should be able to be. What's your succession law? While most starts have you in gavelkind with male preference, the celtic areas are sometimes start with tanistry (family elective).

Comment: @Affine - Succession law is cognatic-agnatic gavelkind.

Comment: Your son should be sole heir under agnatic-cognatic gavelkind. Did you legitimize him or just acknowledge him? Does he have the "Legitimized bastard" trait?

Comment: @Nix - I did think it was strange.  He has the "legitimised bastard" trait and had the blood drop (gold outline) indicating he was my dynasty.  When I hovered over it it said "my son", but the crown symbol never transferred to him from my daughter.

Comment: You didn't make him a bishop or anything?

Comment: Nope.  I'm wondering if it was just a bug.

Comment: Have you tried saving/restarting/reloading? I've sometimes found this to "clear" odd succession glitches

Answer (score 1):

> A legitimized bastard becomes a permanent member of the dynasty of the legitimizing parent, and is allowed to inherit from both parents.
>   *[(source)](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Bastard)*

There are still a few reasons which may prevent your son from becoming, when his time comes, the Petty King of Munster *[(source)](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Succession#Disqualification)*:

- being a member of the Clergy
- having taken the vows and become a monk
- being a member of a Holy Order
- having been castrated (ouch !). *No balls, no crown.*